# What is the difference between "anarĥiisto" and "anarkiisto"?

Tags: translation, word-difference

I was looking for a translation of the word *anarchist* [on the web](https://glosbe.com/en/eo/anarchist) and I found two words to say it: *anarĥiisto* and *anarkiisto*. What is the difference between those two words?

The website where I made my research says:

> **anarĥiisto** { noun } 
>   An advocate of the ideologies of anarchy.
>
> **anarkiisto** { noun } 
>   Person practicing anarchism.

With those definitions, I want to say the first one is more a thinker and the second one an actor/maker. The problem is that the [French page](https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/eo/anarchiste) doesn't have the same definition for *anarkiisto* :

> **anarkiisto** { noun } 
>  
>   Personne prônant l'anarchisme.

It says an *anarkiisto* is a person who advocates anarchism. It is the exact same definition of *anarĥiisto*.

So, who have I to believe? Have the two words the same meaning or is there a difference?

Comment: See also this question and its answers/ Vidu ankaŭ https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-happened-to-the-letter-%c4%a5-during-the-evolution-of-esperanto-from-zamenhof-to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words are synonyms of each other. For a lot of words with the letter ĥ, there's an alternative word. Most of the time it's replaced by the letter k. These synonyms are invented because some people think the letter ĥ is too hard to pronounce, and that it shouldn't exist.

Some examples:

- teĥniko - tekniko
- ĥemio - kemio
- meĥanismo - mekanismo
- ĥameleono - kameleono
- arĥitekturo - arkitekturo

Comment: Have a look at the recent and extensive response of the _Lingva Konsultejo_ of the Esperanto Academy, too: http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Lingva_Konsultejo_(parto_11)#Demando_pri_.27k.27_kaj_.27.C4.A5.27

Comment: In particular, I believe *every* word with *rĥ* has an alternative with *rk*. In same other cases this is not possible: *eĥo* could not be replaced with *eko* because that already exists.

Comment: Eĥo could be replaced with eho without any conflict with existing words, tho. I wonder why this is not mentioned that often. The only triplet I know is koro, horo, ĥoro, where you need a completely different word "koruso" if you prefer avoiding the ĥ-sound.