# Ĉu estas diferenco inter "teĥniko" kaj "tekniko"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Is there a difference between ["teĥniko"](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/te%C4%A5niko) and ["tekniko"](http://simplavortaro.org/vorto/tekniko)? According to ReVo, both seem to signify "technique", i.e. the skillful way of doing, performing or producing something specific.

Comment: Vidu ankaŭ: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-happened-to-the-letter-%c4%a5-during-the-evolution-of-esperanto-from-zamenhof-to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between both words and both words are understood. You can simply choose which word you prefer to use. I myself usually prefer the forms with the letter "ĥ".